# Shortcut key to edit cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on a Macbook Pro, working quite a lot in Google Sheets. I've deactivated the F-keys (so it's not an option to use <kbd>F2</kbd>). I can't find a shortcut for editing a cell with text in it. If it's an empty cell I can just start typing. But if I want to edit a cell with content in it, I can't seem to find a way to do it. I've tried these:

- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> is not an option.

I don't want to use the mouse (double-click on a cell to edit)...It's so clumsy and slow.

Comment: Sorry to be obnoxious, but why deactivate the F-keys? It's one of the more annoying things I find in the Apple default setup - I always change the setting to use regular F-keys on all Macs I've regularly used. Plays better with applications expecting a PC-style keyboard that way, and I don't fiddle with the screen brightness _that_ often... ;)

Comment: Because I'm on a Macbook Pro 15'', with the touchbar. The touch-bar is good for usual stuff, that the Apple-keys offered you: volume-control, brightness, etc. But to find an F-key, without looking at the keyboard is as easy as finding the G-spot; so it's better to assume that it's simply not there and move along. :-)

Comment: Fair enough @Zeth. The Touchbar was one of the horrible things I disliked about my 2017 MBP. ;) But, I've since then switched jobs and am using Linux on the desktop instead... :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and it should start editing your current cell.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid now

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>F2</kbd> seemed like a cumbersome keyboard shortcut for such a basic thing as editing a cell, so I was really relieved when I finally realised that just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> works too.

Comment: This is the answer. How the hell did I never realize this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the hope of avoiding disappointment should anyone happen on this expecting a more comprehensive answer, the editing shortcut keys for a Mac are listed at [M+ Google/Archive](https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/m-google-project-archive/accessibility/google-spreadsheet-keyboard-shortcuts---mac):

[image: WA107404 shortcut keys for Mac editing]

```
Action                  Shortcut
Undo                    ⌘+Z
Insert time             ⌘+Shift+:
Insert date             ⌘+;
Fill range              ⌘+Enter
Fill down               ⌘+D
Fill right              ⌘+R
Insert/edit comment     Shift+F2
Redo                    ⌘+Y
Edit a cell             Fn+F2
Ignore changes          Escape
```

Details should also be accessible through the Help menu (image from a Windows system):

[image: Help menu]

Answer (score 1):

Wups... I can see, that when I press the <kbd>FN</kbd>, then the `F`-keys are actually showed in the touch-bar.

So <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is actually an option. However... I improved it, but mapping <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> using [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) (really easy to setup these shortcuts in there).